# How to stop and start Azure databricks job on existing cluster using PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, databricks, azure-databricks

I am working on writing PowerShell script for databricks to start and stop existing job on existing cluster.
I found out we can use API calls but I am not sure how script will look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use databricks job api to start/stop/create/delete. for sample attaching postman test image.

Example -

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://adb-54965655965.7.azuredatabricks.net/api/**2.0/jobs/run-now**' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer < put your databrciks user token>' \
--data-raw '{
  "job_id": 4733
}'
```

[Postman test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/949x0.png)

Please follow URL and will see all commands. There it will give you only high lighted part for your complete url and body.

adb-54965655965.7.azuredatabricks.net/api/**2.0/jobs/run-now**

https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use two ways of creating PowerShell script in order to reach out with databricks API, however, first of all, you must have had to learn about job cluster, cluster all purpose and cluster with notebooks deploy because each one has different json body and therefore different approachs.

1. Using Curl
   **Install-Module -Name DatabricksPS**
   An Example jobCluster creation (job + cluster)

   $create_job_body='
   {
   "name": "job_cluster_test",
   "job_clusters": [{
   "job_cluster_key": "default_cluster",
   "new_cluster": {
   "spark_version": "11.3.x-scala2.12",
   "node_type_id": "Standard_DS3_v2",
   "spark_conf": {
   "spark.speculation": true
   },
   "autoscale": {
   "min_workers": 1,
   "max_workers": 3
   }
   }
   }],
   "tasks": [{
   "task_key": "task_01",
   "description": "execute task01",
   "depends_on": [],
   "notebook_task": {
   "notebook_path": "/Shared/test/test_notebook"
   },
   "job_cluster_key": "default_cluster",
   "max_retries": 0,
   "min_retry_interval_millis": 0,
   "retry_on_timeout": true,
   "timeout_seconds": 3600,
   "email_notifications": {}
   }],
   "format": "MULTI_TASK"
   }'|ConvertFrom-Json

   ```
    $create_job_result=Invoke-DatabricksApiRequest -Method "POST" -EndPoint     "/2.1/jobs/create" -Body $create_job_body
    $execute_job_body=@{"job_id"=$create_job_result.job_id}
    $execute_job_result=Invoke-DatabricksApiRequest -Method "POST" -EndPoint     "/2.1/jobs/run-now" -Body $execute_job_b

    do{
    Start-Sleep 20
    $run_result=Invoke-DatabricksApiRequest -Method "GET" -EndPoint "/2.1/jobs/runs/get?    run_id=$($execute_job_result.run_id)"
    $current_state="|$($run_result.state.life_cycle_state)|"
    Get-Date -Format "dddd MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm K"
    }while ($job_states.contains($current_state))
   ```

   2. Using powershell CMLET.

      Get-DatabricksClusters - Returns a list of all clusters in your workspace
      New-DatabricksCluster - Creates/Updates a cluster
      Start-DatabricksCluster
      Stop-DatabricksCluster
      Update-DatabricksClusterResize - Modify the number of scale workers
      Remove-DatabricksCluster - Deletes your cluster
      Get-DatabricksNodeTypes - returns a list of valid nodes type (such as DS3v2 etc)
      Get-DatabricksSparkVersions - returns a list of valid versions
      example:
      Set-DatabricksEnvironment -AccessToken "dapi123...def" -ApiRootUrl     "https://westeurope.azuredatabricks.net"
      Get-DatabricksCluster | Stop-DatabricksCluster
      Get-DatabricksWorkspaceItem -Path "/"
      Export-DatabricksWorkspaceItem -Path "/TestNotebook1" -LocalPath     "C:\TestNotebook1_Export.ipynb" -Format JUPYTER

      Start-DatabricksJob -JobID 123 -NotebookParams @{myParameter = "test"}